# how to integrate a personal plugin in swift

Tags: ios, swiftui

I built a personal plugin in swift.

But in my code, I want to call a function from plugin that return a simple string.

```
import SwiftUI
import hello_package_plugin

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showDetails = false
    let hello = HelloPackagePlugin(registrar: <#FlutterPluginRegistrar#>) //I'm not sure working!!!
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(showDetails ? "Close details" : "Show details") {
                showDetails.toggle()
            }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

                        if showDetails {
                            Text("Hello")
                                .font(.largeTitle)
                        }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

How I can print the function?

```
hello.sayHello()
```

Comment: Usually I remove incorrect tags from questions but here I believe the question could be improved by adding more tags.

Comment: No, I don't know flutter so I am not sure what tags to add

Comment: @joisberg what are you trying to achieve? It looks like you try to call dart code from a flutter app within your SwiftUI app which is weird.

Comment: I buit a plugin with dart but I export to swift @bbjay